# Если нет focus, то выполнить

Tags: jquery, focus

Каким образом сделать, чтобы если не было **focus**, то выполнялось:

```
$('#main_shop_create_form_shadow').addClass('active');
```

Сам код (при **focus**):

```
$('#shop_name').focus(function() {
 $('#main_shop_create_form_shadow').addClass('active');
});
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

С **hover** это легко:

```
   $('#shop_name').hover(function() {
    $('#main_shop_create_form_shadow').addClass('active');
   }, function() {
    $('#main_shop_create_form_shadow').removeClass('active');
   });
```

А как с **focus**? :)

Comment: Обрабатывайте событие blur

Comment: @likerRr, не работает же :( $('#shop_name').blur(function() { $('#main_shop_create_form_shadow').addClass('active'); }, function() { $('#main_shop_create_form_shadow').removeClass('active'); });

Comment: @ModaL, blur и focus - отдельно надо передавать по одному callback'у в каждую функцию

Comment: @ModaL, как используете - так и работает :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то:

```
$('element').focus(function(){
  console.log('+');
});
$('element').blur(function(){
  console.log('-');
});
```

Comment: @dekameron, благодарю! Это верное решение.

Comment: Не удержался х)

    $('element').focus(function(){
      console.log('+');
    }).blur(function(){
      console.log('-');
    });